# WordPress site isn't displaying images on the front end correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

It is having problems displaying images. I think it could be a CSS, JS or caching issue?  Project thumbnails and even normal images are not displaying. They appear in the media library folder fine, just not on the front end. The site is: https://www.thesaltypen.ie/ - Can supply WordPress login and FTP details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as your site works correctly again?
If not you could check these things:

- Check for errors in the console (there seems to be a problem with your theme (`Failed to load resource`), update it if necessary)
- Use the inspector and check where you would expect images
- Check the database entries, maybe there is a mistake with your connection
- Check your hosting provider. Sometimes they restrict the upload and bandwidth